# Inline style for background image stretch

Tags: css, background-image, inline

Within a div, I am trying to stretch a header image both horizontally (width) and vertically (height). Seems the width stretch can be solved by using:

```
background-size: cover;
background-size: 100% 100%\9; /* IE8 */
```

But for the height (vertical stretch), is there any way to do this? What is the best practice to do this, acceptable across browsers?

```
<div style="background-image: url(&quot;http://ibuild.ph/eascongress/sites/default/files/logos-banners/header-1-revised.png&quot;); background-size: cover; height: 135px;">
<div style="float: left;"><a href="/eascongress/index.php"><img style="width: 441px; height: 117px;" src="/eascongress/sites/default/files/logos-banners/EAS-Logo-Theme-Header-Banner.png" alt="EAS Congress 2015 logo"></a></div>
<div style="float: right; padding-right:17px"><img style="width: 513px; height: 117px;" src="/eascongress/sites/default/files/logos-banners/Global-Local-Benefits-Theme-Header-Banner.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Link to the demo/dev site [here](http://ibuild.ph/eascongress/index.php)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don’t give the element containing the background image a height, but use a percentage padding-top instead. (padding-top in percentage is calculated in regard to the _width_ of an element.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already tried this?

```
.yourclass{
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-ms-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Try to set with px, not with percentage and see if it makes some difference.

Obs.: The demo link is broken.